# Filter List by key gives an empty result

Tags: groovy, jira-rest-api

I am trying to filter a list and only display data containing the `"Total Votes"` Key, but I get an empty result.  Below is the code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;



Logger log = Logger.getLogger("za.co.jira.groovy")

// Get the Change History for the issue key specified above
def issue = get("/rest/api/3/issue/${issue.key}/changelog")
        .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .asObject(Map)
        .body
        
    
    
//Save the results as a map
def issueResult = issue.values.items as List<Map>
    
logger.info("Issue details:" + issueResult.findAll{it.field == 'Total Votes'
```

Output from the `issueResult` variable is

```
[

[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "2",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "3"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "3",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "2"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "2",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "3"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "3",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "4"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "4",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "3"
}]
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "3",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "4"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "4",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "3"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "3",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "4"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "4",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "3"
}],

[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "3",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "0"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "0",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "1"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "1",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "0"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "0",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "1"
}],


[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "0",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "1"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "1",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "0"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],

[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "1",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "0"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "10020",
    "toString": "Done"
}],

[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],
[{
    "field": "Total Votes",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10067",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": "0",
    "to": null,
    "toString": "1"
}],
[{
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],


[{
    "field": "Voting Process Status",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10073",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": null,
    "to": "10121",
    "toString": "Open"
}, {
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}],

[{
    "field": "Voting Process Status",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10073",
    "from": "10120",
    "fromString": "Closed",
    "to": "10121",
    "toString": "Open"
}, {
    "field": "Operation",
    "fieldtype": "custom",
    "fieldId": "customfield_10074",
    "from": null,
    "fromString": null,
    "to": "10123",
    "toString": "Single"
}, {
    "field": "status",
    "fieldtype": "jira",
    "fieldId": "status",
    "from": "3",
    "fromString": "In Progress",
    "to": "3",
    "toString": "In Progress"
}]

    
]
```

But logger.info gives an empty result []

Comment: How do you produce the output for `issueResult` (odd to see Maps with double quotes and curly brackets) ? Could not reproduce you error : http://tpcg.io/_L4F7BS

Comment: @edg issueResult comes from issue.values.items as List<Map> and yes, that's what makes it even more challenging. Let me see if I can further simply the issue and update the question if needed\

Comment: I modified def l on tpcg and got this error: 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/cg/root/62f3e0cb955f7/main.groovy: 2: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 2, column 20.
            [ {"field":"status","fieldtype":"jira","fieldId":"status","from":"1","fromString":"Open","to":"3","toString":"In Progress"}],
                      ^

1 error it's pointing to "Open"

Comment: Yes, that is because in groovy Maps do not look like JS or JSON objects. The syntax is `m = [key: value]` square brackets, not curly ones and no double quotes on keys.

Comment: Could the cause of the problem be that the initial result from the API was returned as json? For example: // Get the Change History for the issue key specified above
def issue = get("/rest/api/3/issue/${issue.key}/changelog")
        .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .asObject(Map)
        .body. 
originally returns json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from all the nesting of the items (1 object in a list in an object in a list).
I used the `JsonSlurper` from groovy instead of `org.json.JSONObject`, something like this should work and in the end you get a `List<Map>` as wanted :

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
// Mock of the API response
jsonText = """
{
  "values": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
            "field": "status"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "items": [
        {
            "field": "Total Votes",
            "fromString": "2",
            "toString": "3"
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "items": [
        {
            "field": "Total Votes",
            "fromString": "3",
            "toString": "4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"""

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def objectFromJson = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonText)
// get ALL items but in a list not in a list of list
def items = objectFromJson.values.items.flatten()
def onlyTotalVotesItems = items.findAll {it.field == "Total Votes"}
println(onlyTotalVotesItems)
```